# Waitress is slow despite CPU idle

Tags: python, waitress

I'm using Python with waitress to serve requests. They are being served really slowly and the queue eventually is full and blocked. However the use of CPU is almost nothing, around 2 % of the resources.

I'm serving waitress as

`serve(PrefixMiddleware(app_config), port=8041, url_scheme='http')`

I've tried to add more threads and increase the backlog, with a small improvement but this doesn't scale well.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve that a bigger portion of the CPU is used to actually process the requests?

Comment: Maybe the slowness is caused by io or underlying limits of active user ?

Comment: The network is also almost unused. There are several actives users in this tests, that might be part of the problem. What would be the best option to increase the number of active users that we can serve in parallel